# Crosswalk with Cordova 4.0.0 existing app?

Tags: cordova, crosswalk-runtime, cordova-4

Can I migrate an existing Cordova 4 application to Crosswalk?. In the migration manual https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/migrate_an_application.html says Cordova 3.6 for Crosswalk-10 and newer...but I have a Cordova 4.0.0 app.

I followed the instructions in the migration manual. I got to build the app after import crosswalk and modify app dependences, but I'm getting nthis error:

02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{co.iridian.shoppingadvisor/co.iridian.shoppingadvisor.CordovaApp}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.iridian.shoppingadvisor.CordovaApp
02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.iridian.shoppingadvisor.CordovaApp
02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
02-20 18:00:22.522: E/AndroidRuntime(1592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each version of Crosswalk is compatible with a specific version of Cordova.

Crosswalk 10 is compatible with Cordova 3.6.

Crosswalk 9 is compatible with Cordova 3.5.

If you use an other version of cordova, it will just not work.

Good news is that it's not because you created your project with version 4 that you can't use it with Cordova 3.6.

Be carefull not to have some changes in platforms/android, in that case, backup those files before you continue.

First we remove the android platform :

```
cordova platform remove android
```

Then we install the version required for the version of crosswalk we want to use :

```
cordova platform add android@3.6.3
```

Then you cann follow the migration manual.